# Why is LIKE producing different results than my regex?

Tags: postgresql, select, regex

Using Postgres 9.5.  Having some trouble using regular expressions to find matching rows.  I tried

```
select * FROM my_object_times t where t.name ~ '/\(.*\)\s*$/'
...
(0 rows)
```

which returned no rows, but this query

```
select * FROM my_object_times t where t.name like '%(%)';
```

returns tons of rows.  How am I messing up the regular expression above?

Comment: The regexp one has to have a ( at the start of the string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward slash is just a regular character in your regular expression, it is not a delimiter like it would be in Perl.  So it will only match strings which have literal forward slashes in them.